# Is it possible to deploy CRM 2011 on premise without Domain Administrator rights?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We are installing an **on-premise** CRM 2011. We are using an OU in the corp AD domain but we **don't have Domain Admin rights**. Is it possible to have a successful deployment? I heard that it is important to have domain admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

As @Noor noted in your duplicate question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/520471/is-it-possible-to-deploy-crm-2011-on-premise-without-domain-administrator-rights).

> This is not needed, but it sure does make the installation much
>   easier.
>
> The Admin rights are required because CRM will create some groups and
>   accounts in AD during the installation.
>
> To install CRM 2011 witout using the administrator account, you will
>   need to create a domain account and give it some permissions on the
>   CRM, SQL and AD, this link from Microsoft will show you all the setup
>   you need in terms of permissions.
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699825.aspx